# Cake PHP Xls Helper utf 8 for sql server

Tags: php, excel, cakephp, utf-8

I am trying to export sql server data into .xls file using cake php.
Xls Helper works fine but when it comes to special (greek) characters I don't get expected result.

I've already tried the following:

1. **Adding in database.php**
   'encoding' => PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_UTF8
2. **Adding in Xls Helper Class**
   header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8");
3. **Adding in Xls Helper Class**
   echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF"; // UTF-8 BOM
   (3rd action totally ruins my format **BUT** I can see the special characters)

The afformationed trials have not lead me to the solution, some help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you embed your data into <![CDATA[]]> ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code seems to do the job:

```
$xls->writeLabel($rowNumber, $columnNumber, mb_convert_encoding($phpArray['ModelName']  ['fieldName'], 'ISO-8859-7'));
```